# How can I sort a multidimensional array by key with adding missing and empty keys?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I've got an idea, but my approach probably isn't correct.

I would like to make an overview based on parameters like this:

**Fruits overview**

1. Choose a param1: e.g. `color`
2. Choose a param2 (optional): e.g.
   `taste`

When the user will choose parameters, I'm making a multidimensional array from my `$fruits` array using this code:

```
$fruits = array(
                    0 => array('name_id' => 'apple2', 'color' => 'green', 'taste' => 'sweet', 'quantity' => '2', 'price' => 'priceless'),
                    1 => array('name_id' => 'apple1', 'color' => 'red', 'taste' => 'sweet', 'quantity' => '3', 'price' => 'cheap'),
                    2 => array('name_id' => 'apple3', 'color' => 'red', 'taste' => 'sweet', 'quantity' => '1', 'price' => '2'),
                    3 => array('name_id' => 'apple4', 'color' => 'blue', 'taste' => 'another', 'quantity' => '2', 'price' => '1'),
                    4 => array('name_id' => 'apple5', 'color' => 'red', 'taste' => 'bitter', 'quantity' => '1', 'price' => '100'),
                    5 => array('name_id' => 'apple6', 'color' => 'red', 'taste' => 'indefinable', 'quantity' => '6', 'price' => '100'),
                    6 => array('name_id' => 'apple7', 'color' => 'red', 'taste' => 'indefinable', 'quantity' => '2', 'price' => '10'),
                    7 => array('name_id' => 'apple8', 'color' => 'green', 'taste' => 'sour', 'quantity' => '2', 'price' => 'priceless'),
                    8 => array('name_id' => 'apple9', 'color' => 'green', 'taste' => 'sour', 'quantity' => '1', 'price' => 'cheap')
                );

$param1 = 'color';
$param2 = 'taste';

foreach ($fruits as $value)
{
    $value[null] = null;
    $multiarray[$value[$param1]][$value[$param2]] = isset($multiarray[$value[$param1]][$value[$param2]])
    ? $multiarray[$value[$param1]][$value[$param2]] + $value['quantity'] : $value['quantity'];
}
```

And the result for `$multiarray` is:

```
Array
(
   ['green']  => Array
                 (
                     ['sweet']  => 2
                     ['sour']   => 3
                 )
   ['red']    => Array
                 (
                     ['sweet']  => 4
                     ['bitter'] => 1
                     ['indefinable'] => 8
                 )
   ['blue']   => Array
                 (
                     ['another'] => 2
                 )
)
```

Then I wanted to sort:

```
ksort($multiarray);
foreach($multiarray &$value) {
       ksort($value);
}
```

So the result was:

[image]

It was almost ready, but unfortunately, it doesn't work like I expected, because of course it sorts values only inside second-dimensional array. But I would like to sort all of my columns in table. Do you have any ideas, how to do that? Should I be adding missing keys with quantity "0" somehow for sorting purposes only?

To be honest, my original table has four dimensions, but how can I do it in a two-dimensional array?

Comment: May we see some sample input that relates to your desired output?  `var_export()` is best.  I don't quite understand how you want the data within the rows to be sorted.  For best support, please provide `$fruits`, `$param1` and `$param2`.

Comment: Kindly provide sample data of `$fruits` by doing `var_export($fruits);`.

Comment: Do you want to build an array of unique attributes like: `$headers[$value[$param2]] = $value[$param2];` while you iterate `$fruits`? Then sort that when the looping is done? We need a [mcve].

Comment: If param2 is optional, what will happen in your code at `$multiarray[$value[$param1]][$value[$param2]]` specifically?  Is there a default value for param2?

Comment: How do you display the values? What gives you the name of the columns? If you know the names of the columns then why do you need to sort the array itself?

Comment: @mickmackusa if param2 will be empty, then my table will have only two columns (with color names and with quantity of fruits), so the problem would no exists. In that case I made `$value[null] = null;` part, so it is still twodimensional array, but the keys of param2 are everywhere null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain an associative array of unique column names with empty strings as values.  This will serve three purposes -- 1. create column heading, 2. Align subarray data, and 3. supply default values in the HTML table where not available.

Summing the deep subarray values is a basic trick of using a multidimensional associative structure and using the null coalescing operator to add from zero when the param2 value is first encountered within param1's subarray.

To enable flexibility in the html generation, use implode to print a dynamic number of cells in each row.

To get the cells in the non-header rows in the right order, lay the real values "over" the default values by merging the data with the defaults first then the real values.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gpuqD))

```
$fruits = [
    ['name_id' => 'apple2', 'color' => 'green', 'taste' => 'sweet', 'quantity' => '2', 'price' => 'priceless'],
    ['name_id' => 'apple1', 'color' => 'red', 'taste' => 'sweet', 'quantity' => '3', 'price' => 'cheap'],
    ['name_id' => 'apple3', 'color' => 'red', 'taste' => 'sweet', 'quantity' => '1', 'price' => '2'],
    ['name_id' => 'apple4', 'color' => 'blue', 'taste' => 'another', 'quantity' => '2', 'price' => '1'],
    ['name_id' => 'apple5', 'color' => 'red', 'taste' => 'bitter', 'quantity' => '1', 'price' => '100'],
    ['name_id' => 'apple6', 'color' => 'red', 'taste' => 'indefinable', 'quantity' => '6', 'price' => '100'],
    ['name_id' => 'apple7', 'color' => 'red', 'taste' => 'indefinable', 'quantity' => '2', 'price' => '10'],
    ['name_id' => 'apple8', 'color' => 'green', 'taste' => 'sour', 'quantity' => '2', 'price' => 'priceless'],
    ['name_id' => 'apple9', 'color' => 'green', 'taste' => 'sour', 'quantity' => '1', 'price' => 'cheap']
];

$param1 = 'color';
$param2 = 'taste';

$result = [];
foreach ($fruits as $fruit) {
    $defaults[$fruit[$param2]] = '';
    $result[$fruit[$param1]][$fruit[$param2]] = ($result[$fruit[$param1]][$fruit[$param2]] ?? 0) + $fruit['quantity'];
}
ksort($defaults);
ksort($result);

echo "<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4>";
    echo '<tr><th></th><th>' . implode('</th><th>', array_keys($defaults)) . "</th></tr>\n";
    foreach ($result as $p1 => $row) {
        $row = array_replace(['label' => $p1] + $defaults, $row);
        echo '<tr><td>' . implode('</td><td>', $row) . "</td></tr>\n";
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Output:

|  | another | bitter | indefinable | sour | sweet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| blue | 2 |  |  |  |  |
| green |  |  |  | 3 | 2 |
| red |  | 1 | 8 |  | 4 |

Comment: Finally I managed it by myself another way, but your answer is much better approach than mine. And your code is so clean and professional! Thanks for your efforts, I learned something anyway, it opened my mind a little more :)